# Extraction of multiple XMLs from a 500mb file

Tags: java, xml, jms

I need to extract XMLs from a huge (around 500mb) file but I have a 32bit JVM which always runs out of heap space.

I have written a program to extract XMLs from this file but to do that the whole file has to be read (I can not go with 100 lines or so per iteration, as I can not make sure the 100th line would be the end of an XML).

SO how  do I do it?

My program for extraction:

```
private static ArrayList<String> extractXml(String xml) {
    String[] newXml = xml.split("\\<\\?");
    ArrayList<String> xmlList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(newXml));
    for(int i = 0; i<xmlList.size();i++){
        if(!xmlList.get(i).contains("xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"")){
            xmlList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    int size = xmlList.size();
    if(xml.contains("#"))
    for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
        xmlList.set(j, "<?"+xmlList.get(j));
        xmlList.set(j,xmlList.get(j).split("\\#")[0]);

    }else
        for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
            xmlList.set(j, "<?"+xmlList.get(j).trim());
            System.out.println(xmlList.get(j));             
        }



    return xmlList;

}
```

The XMLs also have a Header (its a JMSStream header. Like a wrapper on the XML) which I have been successfully removing using above logic.

Sample file content:

```
#---------- #2 : ID:QADC1_HGR1-EMS13112.15DB4FBEA3665328B:4985 ----------#
<MSG_INFO>
    <message type="TextMessage" messageSelector="" receiveTime="2012-09-12T14:37:26.717" jmsServerTimestamp="2012-09-12T14:37:26.775">
        <header JMSMessageID="ID:QADC1_HGR1-EMS13112.15DB4FBEA3665328B:4985" JMSDestination="OPS.FPES.OUTBOUND.FLIGHT.TRACK_A.DISTRIBUTION" JMSDestinationType="Topic" JMSDeliveryMode="2" JMSPriority="4" JMSTimestamp="1347478646775"/>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </message>
</MSG_INFO>
BodyLength=31108
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flightevent">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns1:EventHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/event/header">
            ...
        </ns1:EventHeader>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:Flight xmlns:ns1="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight">
           <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                ...
                <ns3:OperationalFlightLeg xmlns:ns3="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/operationalflightleg">
                    ...
                </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
            </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
            <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                ...
                    ...
                </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
            </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
            <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
               ...
                    ...
                </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
            </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
            <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                ...
                    ...
                </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
            </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
        </ns1:Flight>
    </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>

#---------- #3 : ID:QADC1_HGR1-EMS13112.15DB4FBEA3665328B:4985 ----------#
        <MSG_INFO>
            <message type="TextMessage" messageSelector="" receiveTime="2012-09-12T14:37:26.717" jmsServerTimestamp="2012-09-12T14:37:26.775">
                <header JMSMessageID="ID:QADC1_HGR1-EMS13112.15DB4FBEA3665328B:4985" JMSDestination="OPS.FPES.OUTBOUND.FLIGHT.TRACK_A.DISTRIBUTION" JMSDestinationType="Topic" JMSDeliveryMode="2" JMSPriority="4" JMSTimestamp="1347478646775"/>
                <properties>
                    ...
                </properties>
            </message>
        </MSG_INFO>
        BodyLength=31108
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flightevent">
            <ns0:Header>
                <ns1:EventHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/event/header">
                    ...
                </ns1:EventHeader>
            </ns0:Header>
            <ns0:Body>
                <ns1:Flight xmlns:ns1="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight">
                   <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                        ...
                        <ns3:OperationalFlightLeg xmlns:ns3="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/operationalflightleg">
                            ...
                        </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
                    </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
                    <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                        ...
                            ...
                        </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
                    </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
                    <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                       ...
                            ...
                        </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
                    </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
                    <ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg xmlns:ns2="http://www.wnco.com/opsplatform/flight/flight/scheduledflightleg">
                        ...
                            ...
                        </ns3:OperationalFlightLeg>
                    </ns2:ScheduledFlightLeg>
                </ns1:Flight>
            </ns0:Body>
        </ns0:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you process the data as you read it instead of loading it into memory all at once?

Comment: Can you show some (small) sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JAVA Scanner to extract the XMLs based on a unique property per XML.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      String temp = null;
      String searchedData = null;
      File file = new File(fileLocation);
      try{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);
            scan.useDelimiter("xml version");
            while (scan.hasNext()){
                  temp = scan.next();
                  if(temp.contains("<ns1:EventCorrelationID>153721264</ns1:EventCorrelationID>")){
                        searchedData = temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf("</ns0:Envelope>")+15);
                        System.out.println("xml version"+searchedData);
                  }
            }
      }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should just use a SAX parser. SAX parsers don't read the whole document at once, instead reading the elements sequentially, and it's only loaded into memory as it's read. This is contrary to what you're trying to do and to DOM parsers.

- Here's the [Java trail for SAX parsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).
- Here's [an example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).
- And [one more](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html).

Comment: Would SAX parser get only the XMLs from a file with other contents as well?

Comment: Ah, now that you've uploaded some data, I see. No, it wouldn't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you certainly shouldn't be doing it by loading 500Mb of data into a Java string and then applying a regular expression to the string, which is what you seem to be doing. You need to do buffered reading of the file and examine the contents of each buffer, taking care to check for delimiters that span the boundary from one buffer to the next.

Comment: I used JAVA scanner to solve the problem. I have posted the solution.